# Triggering Windows TDR (Timeout Detection and Recovery)

Tags: windows-7, directx-9, direct3d9

I'm developing a Direct3D9Ex application, and some of my users are having problems with recovery after a TDR event. In order to fix that I need to test it on my machine, but to do that I need a way to trigger a TDR event on demand.
What's the best way to do that?

Comment: There are some [registry keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569918(v=vs.85).aspx) you can use for local testing.

Comment: Use command "DXCap.exe -forcetdr". Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35617090/217909

Answer (score -1):

I was looking into doing the same and found the command DxgkDdiResetFromTimeout (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559815(v=vs.85).aspx)

I have not attempted to implement it though.