# How can I simulate a DeviceLost event with Win2D?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, win2d

I have a `CanvasControl` in a UWP app and I've noticed when I leave my Surface alone for a while and it goes to sleep automatically, the `CanvasControl` no longer works after resuming. The previously drawn bitmap is now blank.

I tried to simulate Suspend/Resume in Visual Studio 2015, but that doesn't seem to cause a problem. It resumes fine.

I have a feeling it has to do with the `CanvasDevice.DeviceLost` event, and although I manage that with the `CanvasControl.CreateResources` event, I can't find a way to easily test it.

I tried the following:

```
// This throws an exception. Not allowed to do this.
myCanvas.Device.RaiseDeviceLost(); 

// and this doesn't report a device lost, but myCanvas becomes unusable.
myCanvas.Device.Dispose();
```

Is there a way to programmatically invoke a `CanvasDevice.DeviceLost` event? How can I fake it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible to trigger a device lost event with an API, but there is a command line tool you can use:

```
DXCap.exe -forcetdr
```

The version of DXCap you need is part of the Graphics Tools for Windows 10 package, for Win10 build 10586 or later:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125501.aspx#InstallGraphicsTools

After installing the VSGD, you can find DXCap in the windows\system32 directory.

Unfortunately it looks like this option is not (yet) documented, but from the command line:

```
  -forcetdr          Don't capture or replay, but simply force a GPU Timeout
                     Detection and Recovery event, then exit.
```

Comment: Excellent! I found the bug instantly! This is probably an important suggestion, maybe you should attach it to the Win2D documentation. Thank you, Simon.

Comment: [One way to force a TDR programmatically](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/108141/how-can-i-test-dxgi-error-device-removed-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

What the @Simon described is documented here at the bottom of the page:

[Handle device removed scenarios in Direct3D 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/handling-device-lost-scenarios)

Direct quote from the link above:

> Visual Studio's Developer Command Prompt supports a command line tool 'dxcap' for Direct3D event capture and playback related to the Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics. You can use the command line option "-forcetdr" while your app is running which will force a GPU Timeout Detection and Recovery event, thereby triggering DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED and allowing you to test your error handling code.